# Linphone for Windows Phone Crash - System.Exception: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Tags: linphone

I get the git source code for Windows Phone (linphone-wp). I pass all steps from readme file and successfully compiled the project. I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I deploy the application. I can access any screen, but after I enter valid connection data for a real SIP account and after success register with a SIP account I receive this error and application crash:

```
   {System.Exception: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
   at Linphone.Core.OutOfProcess.Server.get_LinphoneCore()
   at Linphone.Model.LinphoneManager.get_LinphoneCore()
   at Linphone.Dialer.IsAccountConfigured()
   at Linphone.Dialer.BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
   at Linphone.Dialer.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.Microsoft.Phone.Controls.IPhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedToX(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.RaiseNavigated(Object content, Uri uri, NavigationMode mode, Boolean isNavigationInitiator, IPhoneApplicationPage existingContentPage, IPhoneApplicationPage newContentPage)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.CompleteNavigation(DependencyObject content, NavigationMode mode)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.<>c__DisplayClass7.<NavigateCore_StartNavigation>b__4()}
```

After enabling Native code debug mode:

```
First-chance exception at 0x6B319D91 (libantlr3c.dll) in HeadlessHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000034.
Unhandled exception at 0x6B319D91 (libantlr3c.dll) in HeadlessHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000034.
```

Call stack:

```
libantlr3c.dll!toStringSS(ANTLR3_TOKEN_STREAM_struct * ts, unsigned int start, unsigned int stop) Line 569  C
libantlr3c.dll!toStringTT(ANTLR3_TOKEN_STREAM_struct * ts, ANTLR3_COMMON_TOKEN_struct * start, ANTLR3_COMMON_TOKEN_struct * stop) Line 584  C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!synpred1_belle_sip_message_fragment(belle_sip_messageParser_Ctx_struct * ctx) Line 202429   C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!synpred1_belle_sip_message(belle_sip_messageParser_Ctx_struct * ctx) Line 203391    C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!dfa2_sst(belle_sip_messageParser_Ctx_struct * ctx, ANTLR3_BASE_RECOGNIZER_struct * recognizer, ANTLR3_INT_STREAM_struct * is, ANTLR3_CYCLIC_DFA_struct * dfa, int s) Line 58555 C
libantlr3c.dll!antlr3dfapredict(void * ctx, ANTLR3_BASE_RECOGNIZER_struct * rec, ANTLR3_INT_STREAM_struct * is, ANTLR3_CYCLIC_DFA_struct * cdfa) Line 99    C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!common_request(belle_sip_messageParser_Ctx_struct * ctx) Line 165724    C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!message_raw(belle_sip_messageParser_Ctx_struct * ctx, unsigned int * length) Line 165540    C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!belle_sip_message_parse_raw(const char * buff, unsigned int buff_length, unsigned int * message_length) Line 133    C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!belle_sip_channel_parse_stream(belle_sip_channel * obj, int end_of_stream) Line 509 C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!belle_sip_channel_process_stream(belle_sip_channel * obj, int eos) Line 543 C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!belle_sip_channel_process_read_data(belle_sip_channel * obj) Line 576   C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!belle_sip_channel_process_data(belle_sip_channel * obj, unsigned int revents) Line 598  C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!on_udp_data(belle_sip_udp_listening_point * lp, unsigned int events) Line 190   C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!belle_sip_main_loop_iterate(belle_sip_main_loop * ml) Line 448  C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!belle_sip_main_loop_run(belle_sip_main_loop * ml) Line 478  C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!belle_sip_main_loop_sleep(belle_sip_main_loop * ml, int milliseconds) Line 490  C
belle-sip_no_tunnel.dll!belle_sip_stack_sleep(belle_sip_stack * stack, unsigned int milliseconds) Line 200  C
LibLinphone_no_tunnel.dll!sal_iterate(Sal * sal) Line 745   C
LibLinphone_no_tunnel.dll!linphone_core_iterate(_LinphoneCore * lc) Line 2608   C
Linphone.Core.dll!Linphone::Core::LinphoneCore::IterateEnabled::set::__l12::<lambda>(Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ^ action) Line 1533  C++
Linphone.Core.dll!Platform::Details::__abi_FunctorCapture1<void <lambda>(Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ^),void,Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ^>::Invoke(Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ^ __arg0) Line 857    C++
[External Code] 
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for THREADPOOLWINRT.DLL]
```

I tried on emulators and also on real device (Lumia 640 XL WP8.1 Update 2) and I get the same error.

The log on the phone does not contain any error message.

If I enter, let say wrong password, a "bad credentials" message is received. The crash happen only after success registration on SIP server.

Please help me to fix this issue. Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some long debugging I found the cause of the issue. The issue is related to the push notification functionality that is configured in

> linphone-wp\Linphone\App.xaml.cs

```
// Initialize the push channel 
InitPushChannel();

// Initialize the task to listen to incoming call notifications on the push channel 
InitHttpNotificationTask();
```

I don't use a push notification service, so I commented the code above and it solved the issue.